# How to rename a branch in tortoise svn while keeping history

Tags: tortoisesvn

How can I rename a committed branch in tortoise SVN without loosing history. My senior has come up with the new naming convention and he wants me to follow it throughout on all committed branches. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: I think there is an option when running a dif to take into account renames. Try and rename it with an SVN rename though

Answer (score 1):

Rename the branche:
$ svn move https://server/repos/myrepo/branches/oldbranch\
https://server/repos/myrepo/branches/newbranch

Do an update:
$ svn update

Don't forget to switch any working copies of the old branch with:
$ svn switch URL of the new branche